# Docker bind mount permissions - unexpected mounting as root:root

Tags: docker

I have a directory `/home/foo/mydir` owned by `foo:foo` (uid=1040) that I bind mount in the alpine docker image as such:
`docker run -it --rm -v /home/foo/mydir:/tmp/mydir --user 1040 alpine`

but when I check the directory in the container, it is owned by `root:root`.  Am I crazy?  I thought docker passed through file ownership when mounting in a container?  Is there anyway to retain the permissions (ie have `mydir` owned by `foo:foo` in the container) without chown'ing it in the container?

Comment: try `--user 1040:1040` maybe?

Comment: What's the host operating system?  Have you configured user namespace remapping on the Docker daemon?

Comment: Can't reproduce - I tried running the command `docker run -it -v /home/nick:/home/nick --user 1000:1000 ubuntu bash`, which correctly manages to mount the directory in as UID 1000.

Comment: On macOS, `--user` makes this work only when using the old "osxfs" file sharing mode, not the new gRPC FUSE mode. When I use "osxfs" mode, then `docker run --user ABC:XYZ …` assigns `ABC:XYZ` ownership to any bind-mounted files and directories.

Comment: I have two Ubuntu Jammy machines and this issues happens on one machine, but not the other. They both run the same version of Docker and same configuration, so I'm really confused what's causing this.

Answer (score 3):

I have two Ubuntu Jammy machines and this issues happened on one machine, but not the other. I finally found the cause and the solution.

Apparently the issue is caused by Docker Desktop. On the first machine I only installed the Docker engine. The second machine had Docker Desktop installed, which runs a virtual machine and your containers will run inside that virtual machine. In that case you can't just mount the host directory the same way into the containers, because you need to mount it first into the virtual machine.

One solution is to remove Docker completely (including `~/.docker`), and then only install the Docker engine (https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/).

Alternatively, on the second machine, if you have Docker CE installed too, you can switch back to the "default" context:

```
docker context use default
```

Based on my support enquiry here:

https://forums.docker.com/t/bind-mount-permissions-unexpected-mounting-as-root-root/129328?u=swpppp